# How to use ternary operator to set a variable to true or false based on value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to set a variable to `true` or `false` based on a condition using ternary operator in javascript.

below is what i am trying to do

i am retrieving the value of "source" using `formikBag.values` and if that value is `"source_1"` i want to display span element if its anything other than `"source_1"` i dont want to display span element.

below is my code,

```
const source = formikBag.values[SOURCE];
const isSource1 = React.useMemo(() => ({
    if (source === "source_1") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}), [source]);

return (
    {isSource1 && 
        <span>source name</span>
    }
);
```

in the above code i have used `if` and `else` but i want to use ternary operator to do the same. could someone help me with this.

Comment: `const isSource1 = source === 'source_1'`.

Comment: Do you really need ternary operator? You could just have `return  source === "source_1;" `

Comment: Why do I feel this question is not in the level of a question? And if such, why is it here, as a question? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `if else clause` just use your condition directly

```
const isSource1 = React.useMemo(() => source === "source_1"), [source]);
```

and also you don't need to use `useMemo` hook it doesn't do anything useful  in your case but adds some extra unnecessary work, just use it directly

```
const isSource1 = source === "source_1"
```

Comment: thanks. but this throws an error "this will always return false since the types '{source : string;}' and 'string' have no overlap

Comment: is your `source` variable an object? like this `{source: string}`?

Comment: @stackuser if yes your first way of checking was also wrong. and you need to change it to this: `const isSource1 = source.source === "source_1"`

Comment: when i log the values of formikBag like so formikBag.values i see the output like {source: "source_1"} now logging only source like so formikBag.values[source] gives source_1

Answer (score -1):

```
const isSource1 = React.useMemo(() => ({
   let retValue = (source === "source_1")? true : false
 return retValue 
}), [source]);
```

OR

```
 const isSource1 = React.useMemo(() => ({
       return  (source === "source_1")? true : false
    }), [source]);
```